# css font-face showing different font style from referenced site?

Tags: html, css, font-face, google-webfonts

In one of my site I have used "Bree Serif" font. For that I have used [font face generator](http://convertfonts.com/). Now after generating all the fonts and proper font size I can see that I have used font in [my site](http://www.kratom-uk.co.uk/home/kratom-powder/green-vein-borneo-copy/) style is little bit different from the [referenced site](http://www.herbaleye.co.uk/legal-highs/product/salvia-divinorum-60x-extract/) font. Now can someone tell me what's the issue here? Any help and suggestions will be really apprexciable. Thanks...

Here is the font face generated codes

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BreeSerifRegular';
    src: url('breeserif-regular.eot');
    src: url('breeserif-regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('breeserif-regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('breeserif-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('breeserif-regular.svg#BreeSerifRegular') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: Insufficient information. Please specify what differences you see and which browser(s) you used in testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the path to `breeserif-regular.eot` in your css file is correct?